# JPA findBy with logical condition in method name

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-data-jpa, jpql

I would like to write a JPA method with where and logical condition something like:

```java
User findByEmailAndAgeIsGreaterThanEqualsToXX(String email, Integer XX);
```

Same can easily done by putting

```
@Query("select u from User u where u.email = :email AND u.age >= :age")
User findByEmailAndAge(String email, Integer age);
```

but can it be done from method signature.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can have a look at the official spring documentation for spring-data:

https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/

I think it should be possible with the following Syntax:

```
User findByEmailAndAgeGreaterThanEqual(String email, Integer age);
```